# Multiple assignment in single doesn't work

Tags: vb.net

I am a `C#` guy working in `VB.net`. I am used to do it

```
lblErrorMsg.Text = txtErrorMsg.Value = vDataRow.Item("error_msg")
```

but it doesn't work in `VB.Net`. It sets

`lblErrorMsg.Text = "False"` and `txtErrorMsg.Value = ""` instead of actual value of `vDataRow.Item("error_msg")`.

What's going on here?

Comment: good read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/02/11/chaining-simple-assignments-is-not-so-simple/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.NET that doesn't work, but i also dont like it in C#. In VB the `=` operator has two different purposes:

1. [assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator)
2. [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators) (equal to)

So you are assigning the result of the comparison(which is a `Boolean`) to the `String` variable.

So you have to use this readable approach:

```
txtErrorMsg.Value = vDataRow.Item("error_msg") ' doesn't compile with Option Strict On (see below)
lblErrorMsg.Text = txtErrorMsg.Value
```

But another thing is more important, you should always set [`Option Strict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) to `On`, especially if you're already used to it because you are using C#. You have set it to `Off` because `vDataRow.Item("error_msg")` returns `Object` not `String` and even your comparison-assignment assigns a `Boolean` instead of resulting in a compiler-error. Use this instead:

```
txtErrorMsg.Value = vDataRow.Field(Of String)("error_msg")
```

Comment: As to 'what's going on here?', it's setting lblErrorMsg.text to the result of the equality of txtErrorMsg.Value and  vDataRow.Item("error_msg")

Comment: I, unlike you, personally would have liked `==` to be comparision operator in `VB.net` as most of the common languages use it.

Comment: The `==` was never being questioned. Just that you can do multiple assignments as a single statement in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET treats the single equals in the r-value as a comparison. Hence its not possible to chaining assignment in VB